# Negation at the end of a sentence

Tags: kinship-terms

This question arose due to a translation from Spanish:

> Susana esta aqui pero no nos ve.

Here are two possible translations:

1. Susana is here, but, does not see us.
2. Susana is here but, sees us not.

An answer might be:

3. One worry not.

Here is another example of negation at the end of a sentence:

4. She loves me, she loves me not.

Here is another related set:

5. We are here but she does not feed us.
6. We are here but she feeds us not.
7. One could say, she feeds us not but a loaf of bread!

How is that then defined? Is that colloquial? I think not. So where do you feel that this type of sentence originated from?

Comment: What is your question? As it is written, your question is hard to decipher.

Comment: Is it in a context, then, that English follows a rule that allows for end of sentence negation?  Haha..or does that mean there that it is infinitive, yet if context is imp lied..good thing it was demonstrative.  What then I mean is that I question as to the validity of the English grammatical lexicon when among st.  1 feel that be.  

Can I say, a kin to the old game of petals, "She loves me, she loves me not"?  Is it then false present to say She does not love me.  Well, of course!  Thus the context is derived!

Comment: What will you say when I give you these two sentences:  "We are here but she does not feed us."  "We are here but she feeds us not"  Is the not missing a subject, or is that which follows not a one thing?  One could say, she feeds us not but a loaf of bread!  The direction is all ready there when one presents word fair.

Comment: *Susana is here but sees us not* is okay but not the ordinary way to put it. Does this answer your question?

Comment: How is that then defined?  Is that colloquial? I think not.

Comment: There again we can see it could have meant I think not a thought, or I think not a thing of it, but, it is up being on the path of discovery.

Comment: It is up to context and perceived speaker's intention. If a speaker wishes to continue to be obscure, that's his or her choice  but it won't help effective  communication.

Comment: So where do you feel that this type of sentence originated from?

Comment: Hi Abe, and welcome to EL&U. I've edited your question for clarity and to bring in some information from your comments. Please feel free to [edit] further or to [roll back](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/408967/revisions) the changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to know if a sentence with no auxiliary verb may be negated by placing *not* after the lexical verb, so that *not* falls at the end of the sentence, thus:

> STATEMENT She loves me.
>   DIRECT NEGATION She loves me not.

This negative construction—I call it 'direct' negation because *not* directly negates the lexical verb—was common from the time that *not* arose in Middle English as a supplement (and then a replacement) for the older *ne*. Direct negation remained common and standard through Early Modern English (down to about 1660); but in the 15th century it began to be supplemented (and then replaced) by 'indirect' negation with *do* support, in which only auxiliary verbs may be directly negated, so negating a bare lexical verb requires that it be be recast as the infinitive complement of the 'dummy' auxiliary *DO* :

> INDIRECT NEGATION She does not love me.

By the middle of the 18th century the indirect construction with *do* support had largely supplanted the direct construction, except in literary or very formal discourse. Direct negation lingered here and there (primarily in poetry) until the 20th century, but it is no longer employed even in the most formal registers except for occasional rhetorical or archaicizing effect.

Comment: Put more simply, the version with 'not' at the end of the sentence is very old-fashioned and only survives today in a few traditional  expressions. "She loves me, she loves me not" is an old fortune-telling game where you pick petals off a flower to see which phrase you are saying as you pick the last one.

Comment: Do you call ;do a dummy auxiliary because there are words that better supplement?  I do go to the store.  I do the dishes.  Could the first sentence imply that you do the clause 'go to the store'?  Is it telling of the trueth?

Comment: @AbeShudug No; it's called a 'dummy auxiliary' because it has no semantic content, it's employed as an auxiliary purely for syntactic reasons. In emphatic contexts (*I **do** want to go*) it's a real auxiliary, and in other contexts, like your sentences, it's a lexical verb.